# how to connect multiple classes?

Tags: java, swing

I am newbie in java

```
package assigment;

import java.awt.*;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class view extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new view();
    }

    public view(){
        JFrame f = new JFrame("WELCOME");
        f.setSize(400, 300);
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        controller cl = new controller();

        JButton btnCompany = new JButton ("COMPANY");
        f.add(btnCompany);
        f.setLayout(null);
        btnCompany.setBounds(50, 50, 100, 50);
        btnCompany.addActionListener (cl);
    }
}
```

**contoller class**

```
package assigment;

import java.awt.event.*;
public class controller {

    public static void actioncompany(ActionEvent a,view view) {
        if (a.getSource() == view.btnCompany) {
            System.out.print ("test");
        }
    }
}
```

Problem:

1. Cannot use `controller` class
2. Cannot access `btnCompany` in `controller` class

Comment: Simply use `btnCompany.setActionCommand("COMPANY")` after initializing the `JButton` inside the `view` constructor. Now inside `controller` use `String command = (String) e.getActionCommand(); if (command.equals("COMPANY")) {System.out.println("Test");}`, this will do. Though do learn about [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367), and stick to them :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That code shouldn't even compile since there isn't a field, `view.btnCompany`. The btnCompany variable is local to the constructor and thus invisible everywhere else. Also, as MadProgrammer notes, your controller class (re-name it **C**ontroller) doesn't implement ActionListener and so cannot be used as an ActionListener.

I have other issues with your code:

- Don't use null layout and absolute positioning.
- Do abide by Java naming rules including starting class and interface names with an upper case letter so that others can more easily understand your code.
- Yes, separate out your control from your view.
- Most all fields should be private, and so view.BtnCompany shouldn't be visible, even if the field existed.
- ActionListeners must implement the ActionListener interface or extend a class that implements the interface such as AbstractAction.

Comment: already did that but  btnCompany.addActionListener (cl) will error

Comment: @YuukiRito: already did what? And what error? Please give more information, enough to allow us to be able to help you.

Comment: @YuukiRito `controller` doesn't implement `ActionListener`, nor does it provide an implementation of `actionPerformed` from the `ActionLIstener` interface, so you can not use it as a `ActionListener` to `btnCompany`.  A better approach would be either use the [Action API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) or set the `JButtons` `actionCommand` property and check that in your `ActionListener`.  See [How to use Actions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) for more details

Comment: method addActionListener in class AbstractButton cannot be applied to given types

Comment: @YuukiRito: as Mad discusses above, you must pass an ActionListener into the `addActionListener(...)` method, and your class does not implement the ActionListener interface. You will want to have it implement this interface, and then give it a proper `public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)` method.

Comment: can you give me example coding?
sorry because i'm still newbie for java

Comment: @YuukiRito See [**How to use Actions**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) for more details

Comment: @YuukiRito You may also want to take a look [Interfaces](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/createinterface.html) tutorial

Comment: @YuukiRito: check out the complete [Swing Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html) for all the details.